# Indent error in iron python

Tags: python

```
flucommands = """
Library:
    CEL:
    &replace EXPRESSIONS:
    MassFlowRate = """

flucommands = flucommands + 0.43 + "[kg s^-1]"

flucommands = flucommands + """
Temp = """

flucommands = flucommands + 843.15 + "[K]"

counttt = 1
while (counttt<=3):
flucommands = flucommands + "PorositySub" + countt 
flucommands = flucommands + " = " + 0.75 + "\n" 
counttt = counttt + 1
```

i get error

> 'flucommands = flucommands + "PorositySub" + countt' error is 'expect
>   an indented block'

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know about Python's strict rules on indentation? You should [read up on it.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

Comment: Apart from indent @while there are many errors like you're adding string to a float,string to an int

Answer (score 3):

This needs indenting:

```
while (counttt<=3):
    flucommands = flucommands + "PorositySub" + countt 
    flucommands = flucommands + " = " + 0.75 + "\n" 
    counttt = counttt + 1
```

python uses indentation instead of braces (in some other languages) for statement blocks.

Without this your `while:` loop is not defined hence the error you received.

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm and https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/indentation.html